# EDK Xilinx : File fileset.txt could not be opened in $XILINX directory

Tags: path, installation, settings, fpga, xilinx

At the first, I have a problem with my EDK.
I cannot open the EDK (Xilinx Platform Studio).
I got this error...

```
setting XILINX_EDK=C:\Xlinx\12.3\ISE_DS\EDK
Environment variable XILINX is not set -A compitable version of ISE tools must be
installed and setup for EDK to run.

 Press enter to close
```

And then, I change the path.

In win 7, I right click on the computer --> Properties --> advanced systems settings --> Environment Variable --> New -> Variable name (Xilinx) and Variable Value (C:\Xilinx) -->Ok

When i tried to launch again the EDK (Xilinx Platform Studio), I got another error message..

```
  error : File fileset.txt could not be opened in $XILINX directory
```

How to solve this Problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your XILINX variable pointing to "C:\Xilinx\12.3\ISE_DS\ISE"  where the fileset.txt is located.

Answer (score 0):

In version 14.7 you need to set:

```
XILINX = C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE
XILINX_EDK = C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK
```